# RegEx for 5 digit zip or empty

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regex that checks for a 5 digit number `^\d{5}$`

How do I change it so that it returns true also for an empty string?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var regex = /^\d{5}$/;

alert(regex.test(12345));
alert(regex.test(''));
</script>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Enclose it in `()` and add a `?` to make the entire pattern optional.  Effectively, you are then either matching `^\d{5}$` OR `^$` (an empty string).

```
var regex = /^(\d{5})?$/;

console.log(regex.test(12345));
console.log(regex.test(''));
// true
// true

// Too long, too short
console.log(regex.test(123456));
console.log(regex.test('1'));
// false
// false
```

Note that unless you intend to do something with the 5 digits other than prove they are present, you can use a non-capturing group `(?: )` to save a tiny bit of resources.

```
var regex = /^(?:\d{5})?$/;
```

Comment: Thanks, so the '?' alone is enough, do I need the '$'?

Comment: @RegisteredUser Keep the `$` on the end, but surround `\d{5}` in `()` and place `?` directly after it.

Comment: #five is failing