# RegexValidator for Zipcodes

Tags: regex, django, validation

I have been working with Django and RegexValidator on a field where I would only like to save a valid US Zipcode in the format of DDDDD or DDDDD-DDDD.

I have set up my variable in the model as the following:

```
zip = models.CharField(
    max_length=10,
    null=True,
    blank=True,
    help_text=_("Zipcode"),
    validators=[RegexValidator(
        regex=r'^(^[0-9]{5}(?:-[0-9]{4})?$)?$)',
        message=_(u'Must be valid zipcode in formats 12345 or 12345-1234'),
    )],
)
```

At this point, I am trying to create a regex that will also save empty strings as well. I have tried to look at the following questions [RegEx for 5 digit zip or empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127515/regex-for-5-digit-zip-or-empty)
[Regex empty string or email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5063977/regex-empty-string-or-email)
and tried adding a "|" before, as well as an "?" at the end.

Any other suggestions or advice?

Comment: Have you seen: http://django-localflavor.readthedocs.org/en/latest/localflavor/us/ ?

Comment: yes and I believe thats for the form, I just wanted it on the field itself because data gets saved to the database outside of the form as well.

Comment: There's a model field and just a form field... what else are you looking for?

Comment: Ah I missed that, Thank you!!! going to try now.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you just want this as your regex: `^(^[0-9]{5}(?:-[0-9]{4})?$|^$)`

It matches either an 5 digit string followed by an option dash and four digits or an empty string.

This was tested in the [online regex tester](https://regex101.com/#python)

Comment: when i enter '' I get ```Your pattern does not match the subject string.```but there might be something else in my code thats blocking this from saving. im going to revisit and try with this

Comment: ok, let us know how it goes. (also, just FYI, I believe the initial carat is unnecessary)